# Group a sub-set of a result set by time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an audit table where specific actions are being recorded (such as 'access', 'create', 'update' and so on). I am selecting these records so that they can be displayed in a table to the administrative user.

This works fine when I select all the records for a particular entity. However, because I am using the Post-Redirect-Get pattern, the 'access' records are being logged on every page view. In a typical session an end user may hit the same page 6 or 7 times in the same 5 minute window. As a consequence, the administrative user is having to scroll through quite a few redundant access records and this is understandably distracting from the user experience.

To solve this problem, I have written two queries. The first will look for all records that are not access records. The second will look for access records and then groups them into ten minute intervals. I then `UNION` these two queries and order by the datetime.

```
-- Select non 'access' records
SELECT 
     [ORIGIN_ID]
    ,[ORIGIN_ID_TYPE]
    ,[REFERENCE_ID]
    ,[REFERENCE_ID_TYPE]
    ,[ACTION_TYPE_ID]
    ,CAST([ORIGINAL_VALUE] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS ORIGINAL_VALUE
    ,CAST([CHANGED_VALUE] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS CHANGED_VALUE
    ,[CREATED_BY]
    ,[CREATED_ON]
FROM [HISTORY] 
WHERE [ORIGIN_ID] = 500 AND [ORIGIN_ID_TYPE] = 4 AND [ACTION_TYPE_ID] != 1

UNION

-- Select 'access' records and group them into 10 minute intervals by ts
SELECT 
     [ORIGIN_ID]
    ,[ORIGIN_ID_TYPE]
    ,[REFERENCE_ID]
    ,[REFERENCE_ID_TYPE]
    ,[ACTION_TYPE_ID]
    ,CAST([ORIGINAL_VALUE] AS VARCHAR(255)) AS ORIGINAL_VALUE
    ,CAST([CHANGED_VALUE] AS VARCHAR(255)) AS CHANGED_VALUE
    ,[CREATED_BY]
    ,DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [CREATED_ON]) / 10 * 10, 0) AS CREATED_ON
FROM [HISTORY]
WHERE [ACTION_TYPE_ID] = 1 AND [ORIGIN_ID] = 500 AND [ORIGIN_ID_TYPE] = 4
GROUP BY 
     [ORIGIN_ID]
    ,[ORIGIN_ID_TYPE]
    ,[REFERENCE_ID]
    ,[REFERENCE_ID_TYPE]
    ,[ACTION_TYPE_ID]
    ,CAST([ORIGINAL_VALUE] AS VARCHAR(255))
    ,CAST([CHANGED_VALUE] AS VARCHAR(255))
    ,[CREATED_BY]
    ,DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [CREATED_ON]) / 10 * 10, 0)

ORDER BY [CREATED_ON] DESC
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/61606b/1) (I had a limited amount of data SQLFiddle would allow me to upload)

I feel like there may be a better way to do this that does not require me to use `UNION`. In order to do it this way I had to cast my `TEXT` columns to `VARCHAR` columns and I feel like there could be a better alternative. Any suggestions as to how this query can be improved?

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the union by using these two groupings. The second one also becomes the new expression for the combined `created_on` column. The first can also be used to control sorting and then otherwise discarded. (Don't forget to remove the filter on `action_type_id` too.):

```
case when action_type_id <> 1 then 1 else 2 end, 
case when action_type_id <> 1
    then created_on
    else DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, [CREATED_ON]) / 10 * 10, 0)
end
```

This will cause the query to treat the two types of actions as distinct for purposes of aggregation. Since you do want to keep every row with a non-1 action, you don't collapse those into ten-minute blocks at all.

Note that this wouldn't quite work as is if it's possible to have two such rows recorded with the same timestamp. You'd need to group on another ID (or just `row_number()`) to get around that but I suspect that'll be unnecessary.

Comment: Hi Shawn - I am not sure I follow. Action Type Id can be a value from 1 to 6. The example I uploaded to SQLFiddle did not represent all the possible values as it has some unfortunate limitations on just how much data you can upload in the 'schema'. I think maybe I see where you are going with this, but 1 and 2 are just some of the possible values for action type

Comment: @lofacture Think of 1 and 2 as names for the two parts of your union. It's really unrelated to the action type values. You can easily change those to anything you find more descriptive like "Access" and "Other" or whatever you like.

Comment: SQL is not my strongest skill - I am still having trouble understanding where these two case statements are intended to go - they are supposed to replace my union keyword? It seems like maybe you are suggesting that I add these two statements to the GROUP BY section of the second query and remove the top query alltogether. When I do that, I do indeed get my CREATED_ON grouped into ten minute intervals. But then I lose the other action types from the result set.

Comment: My mistake. I had forgotten to remove the WHERE ACTION_TYPE_ID = 1 from the second query WHERE clause.  Let me take another look and make sure this is correct.

Comment: The result sets between my original union and the new query are very different. I had to make a couple of assumptions about where you meant to place them. Thank you for the effort but I am having trouble understanding what you meant.

Comment: Sounds like you've done it right. You'll have to explain what's different then.

Comment: I think we are miscommunicating - I have not been successful in implementing your suggestion.  I do not understand where you are suggesting I put the case statements

Comment: Communication is fine and I don't see how you could have written that query and that question yet not understand what I'm talking about. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/61606b/14

Comment: You may think our communication is fine, but communication involves at least 2 people.  I am telling you as politely as I can that I don't follow what you're saying.  Now that you've shown me what you mean, I can see where you intended for me to use those case statements.  I appreciate your help.